# Elasticsearch Query DSL

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I get log files from my firewall which i want to filter for several strings.
However the string contains always some other information. So i want to filter the whole string for some specific words which are always in the string: "User" "authentication" "failed.

I tried this but i do not get any data from it:

```
  "query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gt": "now-15m"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "User AND authentication AND failed"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}
}

However i cannot find the syntax for specific filtering words in strings. Hopefully some of you can help me.

This is the message log ( i want to filter "event.original"): [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwYT2.png)

Comment: Are you sure the timestamp of that document is within the last 15 minutes ? I tried that query string and it should work

Comment: Yes definitely, i am doing some tests live, so it should be. Does it make any difference if i specify the timestamp in the query or in the GUI from kibana? Because the specified time needs to be set in Kibana too?